# puppet rspec no such file to load -- rspec-puppet (LoadError)

Tags: 10.04, ruby, puppet, gem

I have no prior experience at all of ruby.  I am not interested in ruby (and so have no knowledge of rails etc) as such but am using puppet to manage a group of servers.  I have written some modules and the rspec-puppet system looks like it would be very useful.

However, I cannot get rspec-puppet to work

I am using Ubuntu LTS 10.04

I have installed puppet rspec using the directions on their web page

What I actually did

```
apt-get install rubygems # (installs 1.8)
gem install rspec-expectations
gem install rspec-puppet
```

I also installed librspec-ruby1.8

Then I ran rspec-puppet-init in a puppet module directory I'd already made (it's a working puppet module)

I made a file as defined in the tutorial

```
$ more spec/defines/rule_spec.rb 
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'vanusers::rule' do
let(:title) { 't1' }

it { should contain_class('vanusers::JamieA') }
end
```

but when I try and run it there is a mysterious dependancy issue

```
$ spec spec/defines/rule_spec.rb 
/home/jamie/git/puppet/modules/vanusers/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rspec-puppet (LoadError)
    from /home/jamie/git/puppet/modules/vanusers/spec/spec_helper.rb:1
    from ./spec/defines/rule_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from ./spec/defines/rule_spec.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:15:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14:in `load_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/options.rb:132:in `run_examples'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/spec:3
```

Here is the solution I came up with in the end::

```
apt-get install rubygems
gem install rspec-expectations rspec-puppet puppet-lint puppetlabs_spec_helper
```

so your path picks up the gem stuff

```
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

cd into module and

```
rm spec/spec_helper.rb

rspec-puppet-init
```

replace Rakefile with

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
require 'puppetlabs_spec_helper/rake_tasks'
```

Then "rake spec" to run tests or "rake lint" to check files

http://sysadvent.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/day-22-getting-started-testing-your.html
was an excellent source of info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and the fix was to put the following in my `spec_helper.rb` file:

`require 'rubygems'`

at the top of the file. I was then able to run `$ rake rspec` successfully.

Comment: thanks for that, I've added the solution I came up with to the question